# flutter after wakeup app restart from main in ios

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a app(run in debug mode) in Flutter  that starts with login and, after authentication, loads  a drawermenu.
In IOS if app  goes to sleep and wakes up after some minutes it restart from login instead to show drawermenu.

Why this strange behavior ?

Comment: You need to save the login credentials and persist them so that when the app is restarted it knows your user is authenticated. You can check this link out for more info: https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/key-value/

Comment: I've already thought this and persist credential with shared_preferences but the problem is: "why the app restart after wakes up ?"

Comment: What do you mean by wakes up? You mean someone locked their phone and then unlocked with the app on the foreground?

Comment: @Serl Yes, I do.

Comment: I think the main reason would be how much memory your app is using. If it is using too much memory or if the phone has low battery, the OS probably closes it and then restarts once the user unlocks the phone :)